# Angular js dir-paginate with animations

Tags: angularjs, materialize, dirpagination

I am using `dir-paginate` with filtering and ordering.I want to implement animations for better UI and i cant seem to find a reference.

I am aware of http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/yo-yo-css3-keyframes-animation but this seems to work for `ng-repeat` not for dir-paginate.
What am i missing.

I am not using Bootstrap, instead materializecss.